# sql server split string after comma in order wise

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SELECT @sdate = '20208B9B-FF27-4A30-859A-F6E907B40B08,DFO,E3EB5362-2E57-4778-A291-0740B6B49514,20210504,20210603'

if i use this the order is interchanging
`enter code here`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VALUE)SNO,VALUE  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@sdate,',')

i need output like this  in order wise`enter code here`
20208B9B-FF27-4A30-859A-F6E907B40B08
DFO
E3EB5362-2E57-4778-A291-0740B6B49514
20210504
20210603

Comment: You can't reliably use `STRING_SPLIT` here, as it generates an _unordered_ set of records.  If you use it, it might appear to work, but there is no guarantee of this.

Comment: Use @Larnu knows the answer to this.  Maybe he can help here.

Comment: You'll find examples of a string split function that also returns the ordinal position with an internet search.

Comment: instead of string split function we have to do using charindex may be, because the order is changing while using string split function